# Resource could not be found asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http-post, antiforgerytoken

I am familiarizing myself with asp.net mvc,  Identity and trying a simple log off but get `The resource cannot be found.`

in my html page

```
<li><a href="@Url.Action("LogOff", "Account")" id="home">Log off</a></li>
```

and this is in the AccountController

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult LogOff()
    {
        AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

and this in my route config file

```
 routes.MapRoute(
         null,
         "LogOff",
         new { controller = "Account", action = "LogOff" }
```

What could I be missing?

Comment: Href use GET method, but seems you don have GET method for that action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply putting by removing HttpPost

```
public ActionResult LogOff()
{
    AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

works for me

Comment: Now it does for me as well, tanks

Answer (score 3):

Remove `[HttpPost]` from `LogOff` method

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult LogOff()
{
    AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the post method to log off. See the below example.

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" })) {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a>
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

By default when you creating project with some Authentication it creates `LogOff` method with `HttpPost` attribute.

So You have two ways to fix it

**first** one is to remove this attribute. And let your Code looks like

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult LogOff()
{
    AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

**second** one is to change your html to use `@Html.BeginForm` with POST method [docs here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform%28v=vs.118%29.aspx).

By default projects used second type of realization

**EDIT**
While I was typing this answer **Rad** give an sample how to use BeginForm helper [here it is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30475094/2115584)